# Don't understand why it only put the first int into array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I would like to create a progress bar using Js. I'm following the online demo made by Cassidy Williams on September 13, 2018.
Link: https://codepen.io/cassidoo/pen/wEXQaG

I added more steps into the steps `div` elements:

```
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step" id="0"></div>
    <div class="step" id="1"></div>
    <div class="step" id="2"></div>
    <div class="step" id="3"></div>
    <div class="step" id="4"></div>
    <div class="step" id="5"></div>
    <div class="step" id="6"></div>
    <div class="step" id="7"></div>
    <div class="step" id="8"></div>
    <div class="step" id="9"></div>
    <div class="step" id="10"></div>
  </div>
```

But when I click the third step the last step status is clicked.
What is the problem with this error? Also, what is the solution to this error?

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you mentioned if I add more steps. I am seeing the line between each circle expanding beyond the circles, some CSS adjustments are required here.
Can you share your full code via jsfiddle please to better understand what you're experiencing?

Comment: If you add the step Id more than 10, The error would happen. When you clicked the circle ID between 3 to 9. The circle ID (10 or even more)  would be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 6 of the JS code, the author have the following:

```
progress(x.target.id);
```

Replace by:

```
progress(+x.target.id);
```

And on lines, 14, 18 and 21, do the same.

```
steps.forEach((e) => {
    if (+e.id === stepNum) { // <-- here
      e.classList.add('selected');
      e.classList.remove('completed');
    }
    if (+e.id < stepNum) { // <-- here
      e.classList.add('completed');
    }
    if (+e.id > stepNum) { // <-- and here
      e.classList.remove('selected', 'completed');
    }
});
```

The HTML id is a string, so a cast is necessary. The conditions misbehave because a string comparison is used instead of a number comparison. By casting the string to a number, it is working as intended.

Comment: Oh, I think that the ID is an integer. But after add "+" before x.target.id . The final result would be not like the origin result. The first circle I clicked, it doesn't have any response.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I also needed to cast the ids in the if statements. Try it now. Regarding the id being a number, they are a string in a number format. HTML attributes are always strings, so when you extract them into your JS code, some casting might be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of David Fontes is only partially correct. You need a typecast for the `e.id` as well to have it function properly.

So replace

```
steps.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.id === stepNum) {
    e.classList.add('selected');
    e.classList.remove('completed');
  }
  if (e.id < stepNum) {
    e.classList.add('completed');
  }
  if (e.id > stepNum) {
    e.classList.remove('selected', 'completed');
  }
});
```

with

```
steps.forEach((e) => {
  let t = e.id * 1;
  if (t === stepNum) {
    e.classList.add('selected');
    e.classList.remove('completed');
  }
  if (t < stepNum) {
    e.classList.add('completed');
  }
  if (t > stepNum) {
    e.classList.remove('selected', 'completed');
  }
});
```

This doesn't solve the line problem though (blue line passing beyond the last circle), this seems to be more CSS related than JavaScript.

**Edit:**

David Fontes updated his answer after I made the corrections, so his answer now fixes all the typecasting.

For the blue line problem:

Change `let p = stepNum * 30;` to `let p = stepNum * 10;`, where **10** is the percentage to move the bar with (11 div, so 10 steps make 10%).

Comment: Oh, it can solve my problem too. Btw Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not 'hardcoded' that fix for line won't help, I mean this:

```
let p = stepNum * 10;
```

So, better solution here is to wrap .progress and .steps with another div and give that div position relative.